# How can you reset InnerBlock content to base template?

Tags: block-editor

I am looking for a method to re-render the `<InnerBlock` template... after I've updated some attributes.

This is my sample code I am working with. Notice the onChange event is where I need my InnerBlocks to reset back to initial template values.

```
export const settings = {
    title: __( 'My Block', 'mytextdomain' ),
    description: __( 'Description', 'mytextdomain' ),
    keywords: [ __( 'block' ) ],
    supports: {
        align: false,
        alignWide: false,
    },
    attributes: {
       'someatt' : {
           'type' : 'string'
        }
    },
    edit: function() {

        let TEMPLATE = {
            'myblocks/myblock': {
                'a':'b',
                'c':'d'
            }
        };

        let output = (
            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelBody
                    title={__('Select', 'mytextdomain')}
                    initialOpen={true}>
                    <SelectControl
                         onChange={(selected_id)=>{

                             //TODO: Update InnerBlocks to reset content back to TEMPLATE

                        }}
                        label={ __('Select Item', 'mytextdomain') }
                        options={ options } />
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>
            <div className="myblock">
                <h1>Some Title</h1>
                <InnerBlocks
                    template={ TEMPLATE }
                    allowedBlocks={ ['myblocks/myblock'] }
                    templateLock={ false }
                    >
                </InnerBlocks>
            </div>
        );

        return output;

    },
    save: () => null
};
```

How can I reset the InnerBlock content after I've made an attribute change?

Alex

Comment: Hi Alex, could you share the code from that component?

Comment: @Alvaro - I've just added by block registration code

Answer (score 3):

When we register a block type we define how the block structure should be in the moment it is added to the editor. After the block type is added to the editor we have an actual block.

The initial template prop in the InnerBlock defines which innerBlocks should be added when adding the (root) block type. Once added the prop has no effect as the block has already been created. From there on we need to modify that specific block props.

So in your case we need to dispatch an action to modify the block data in the store. We could achieve this with `wp.data.dispatch`,  `wp.data.withDispatch` or `wp.data.useDispatch`. My suggestion is to use `wp.data.useDispatch` which makes use of React hooks.

We modify the block innerBlocks using the [replaceInnerBlocks](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/docs/designers-developers/developers/data/data-core-block-editor.md#replaceInnerBlocks) function. This function takes the block `clientId` and an array of blocks.

The thing here is that we are modifying blocks that might have content. I suggest taking a look at how we can deal with it in [this other answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/344975). What we do is take the existent blocks and merge them if necessary with programatically created blocks (using `wp.blocks.createBlock`).

```
const { times } = lodash;
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { createBlock } = wp.blocks;
const { PanelBody, SelectControl } = wp.components;
const { InnerBlocks, InspectorControls } = wp.blockEditor;
const { useDispatch, useSelect } = wp.data;

const TEMPLATE = [
    [
        "myblocks/myblock",
        {
            a: "b",
            c: "d"
        }
    ]
];

export const settings = {
    title: __("My Block", "mytextdomain"),
    description: __("Description", "mytextdomain"),
    keywords: [__("block")],
    supports: {
        align: false,
        alignWide: false
    },
    attributes: {
        a: {
            type: "string"
        },
        c: {
            type: "string"
        }
    },
    edit: props => {
        const { className, clientId } = props;
        const { replaceInnerBlocks } = useDispatch("core/block-editor");
        const { inner_blocks } = useSelect(select => ({
            inner_blocks: select("core/block-editor").getBlocks(clientId)
        }));

        return (
            <div className="myblock">
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody title={__("Select", "mytextdomain")} initialOpen={true}>
                        <SelectControl
                            onChange={selected => {
                                let inner_blocks_new = inner_blocks;

                                /*
                                // If we need to add 3 new blocks
                                inner_blocks_new = [
                                    ...inner_blocks,
                                    ...times(3, () =>
                                        createBlock("myblocks/myblock")
                                    )
                                ];
                                */

                                /*
                                // If we need to remove blocks after the third one
                                inner_blocks_new = inner_blocks.slice(0, 3);
                                */

                                replaceInnerBlocks(clientId, inner_blocks_new, false);
                            }}
                            label={__("Select Item", "mytextdomain")}
                            options={options}
                        />
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
                <h1>{__("Some Title")}</h1>
                <InnerBlocks
                    template={TEMPLATE}
                    allowedBlocks={["myblocks/myblock"]}
                    templateLock={false}
                />
            </div>
        );
    },
    save: () => null
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This method worked

Comment: You are welcome, glad it worked @AlexBik